# How to calculate the conserved energy $E$ from the Lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, field-theory, noethers-theorem

I am reading a PhD thesis that considers the Lagrangian 
$$\mathcal{L}=\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi^\star-U(|\phi^2|)$$
where $\phi$ is a complex scalar field and $U(|\phi|^2)$ is an arbitrary potential.

The thesis states that there is a conserved energy $E$ associated with this Lagrangian given by
$$E=\int d^2x\;\left(\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\phi}|^2 +\frac{1}{2}|\nabla\phi|^2 +U(|\phi|^2)\right).$$

This is stated without proof/derivation (probably because it is trivial) but I can't determine the justification for this form. How would I go about deriving this myself?

Comment: You may *check* it is time independent by use of the E-L equations, no? Have you learned about the energy function in transitioning to the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [David Tong's notes on Quantum Field Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf), page 15.

Comment: It would be better if you summarised the points made there than force readers to follow a link (which may rot in future).

Comment: @jacob1729 I should have, but my understanding is too shallow to confidently summarize it just yet, as I have just begun studying QFT. I just remembered coming across it last night so thought I could point Superbee in the right direction.

Comment: @aRockStr Thanks for linking these notes; they are quite helpful. If this answer is eventually expanded (either by you, myself, or someone else) to summarize the main points then I will accept as best answer.